Min-max of $|(z - x_1)(z - x_2)(z - x_3)|$
Trying to use the multi-parameter (3 parameter) Jacobi smoother on the 2D Convection Diffusion Equation with a $O(h^2)$ discretization.
For the smoothing factor to be minimized, I have to minimize
$$
\{\mbox{maximum over the high frequency region}\{|(1 - w_3 \cdot \text{dinv} \cdot z )( (1 - w_2 \cdot \text{dinv} \cdot z ) (1 - w_1 \cdot \text{dinv} \cdot z ) | \}\}
$$
where $z$ varies over the high frequency region. I can give the expression for that as well. Factoring out $w_3,w_2,w_1$ and simplifying, we have:
$$
\min\{{\max \mbox{ over the high frequency region }}\{| (t - t_1)(t - t_2)(t - t_3) |\}\}.
$$
I need to find the optimal parameters $t_i = 1/w_i$ (they need to be real) so that min-max is obtained. $t = \mbox{dinv} \cdot z$ ranges over some complex domain, which is shown in the picture.
If $t$ was real, then it would've been simpler.
So my question is, how do I find the optimal parameters $t_i$ so that min-max is obtained?
If $t$ was real, say $t \in [a,b]$, we use
$$
x_i = [\cos(2 i - 1) \pi/6]
$$
( zeros of the Chebyshev polynomials in $[-1,1]$ ) and then get
$$
w_i = \frac{2}{(b - a) x_i + ( b + a)}.
$$
Tried doing a similar thing with my complex $t$, took the absolute minimum and maximum to get $a,b$, calculated $x_i$ and took these $x_i$ from $[-1,1]$ to $[a,b]$ but I am not getting the correct results.
Sorry for the long story, I thought it would be better if I explained what I'm doing. In short, just need to find (real) optimal parameters $x_1, x_2, x_3$ so that min-max of $| (z-x_1)(z-x_2)(z-x_3) |$ is obtained, where z is complex.
Note: $t$ is a discrete variable here. If we treat it as a continuous variable, we'll almost get an ellipse I believe.


The $\max$ is over $z$?

Yes, or $t$. @NN2

The problem should be max-min, i.e., maximizing over $z$ after minimizing over $x$. The min max tends to infinity as the norm of $z$ tends to infinity.

I see, thank you. Any idea on how we can minimize over $x$?

The question is not clear. Could you confirm and/or clarify whether the question really is
$$\max_{x_1,x_2,x_3\in \color{red}{\mathcal{C}2}}\left(\min{z\in \color{red}{\mathcal{C}_1}} |(z-x_1)(z-x_2)(z-x_3)|   \right)$$
and what are the constraint domains $\mathcal{C}_1$ and $\mathcal{C}_2$?

I'm still not sure if it's max over $z$ and then min over $x$ or min over $x$ and then max over $z$. We have to minimize over $x$ and we have to minimize over $z$, of that I'm sure. That is the definition of the smoothing factor. Anyways, to answer your question, $x1, x2, x3$ can be any real numbers, we just have to make sure that the absolute value of the product is minimized and $z$ varies over the ( almost ) ellipse region shown in the picture above.

( To clarify, in the case we don't use w-Jacobi, just the normal Jacobi three times, the smoothing factor would be: max over $\text{dinv} \cdot z \in D$ { $(1 - \text{dinv} \cdot z)(1 - \text{dinv} \cdot z)(1 - \text{dinv} \cdot z)$ } and so we just have max over $Z \in D$ { $(1 - Z)(1 - Z)(1 - Z)$ }. We can do this computationally in MATLAB.
$D$ here is the region in the picture above, the ( almost ) ellipse.

Edit: Forgot the absolute value in the smoothing factor above.

The question is still not clear.I suggest you should ask only 1 question (for example, min-max of $| (z-x_1)(z-x_2)(z-x_3) $ and don't mention $t$ or $\text{dinv}$ here). Besides, as I understand, $x_i \in \mathbb{R}$ and $z $ is in the elliptical region. You should clarify now the order of optimization (min-max or max-min?) and the min/max is over what ($z$ or $x_i$?)

$ \text{min}{x1, x2, x3 \in \mathbb{R}} (\text{max}{z \in D} |(z - x1)(z - x2)(z - x3)|) $

It's hard. I don't think we can solve analytically your problem. If the problem were $$\min_{z\in  \mathcal{D}}\left(\max_{x_1,x_2,x_3\in\mathbb{R}} |(z-x_1)(z-x_2)(z-x_3)| \right)$$
we might have closed-form solution.

Sorry no, that's not it. We have to choose $x1, x2, x3$ so that the maximum of the absolute value over D is the smallest.
